# Ishibashi states and Cardy states in CFT

Tags: string-theory, hilbert-space, conformal-field-theory

What are the [Ishibashi states](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=ishibashi+states) and [Cardy states](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=cardy+states) in CFTs? I am familiar with conformal field theory language. It would be great if someone can discuss about the basic idea of these states and their applications.

Comment: Since you are familiar with CFT, there are many good introductory articles available on this topic online, for example http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0411189 written by John Cardy.

Comment: @Meng Cheng , I looked at that. Can you or someone else make the basic picture clear.. Then it will be easier for me to follow Cardy's article. Thanks a lot for the reply!